# FastApi: How to test a function (that's not an endpoints) that has a depends?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, dependency-injection, fastapi

I have an endpoint `/has_email` that depends on `user_has_email`, which itself depends on `get_user_info`.

```
app = FastAPI()

def get_user_info(request: Request):
    user_email = request.username
    user_info = get_user_info(user_email)
    
    return user_info


async def user_has_email(user: User = Depends(get_user_info))
    return 'email' in user:


@app.get("/has_email")
def user_email(user_is_registered=Depends(user_has_email)):
    
    
    if user_is_registered:
        return "Email found!"
    else:
        return "No email found!"
```

I understand how to test `get_user_info` and the endpoint `/user_email`, but I'm having difficulty testing `user_has_email`.

When trying to test `user_has_email`, I'll mock `get_user_info` and I expect it to be a `dict` object, but instead I get a `Depends(get_user_info)` object.

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from asyncio import run

client = TestClient(app)

def mock_get_user_info():
    return {"email": "user@test.com"}

app.dependency_overrides[get_user_info] = mock_get_user_info

def test_user_has_email():

    # I expect this to be `True`, instead I get `Depends(get_user_info)`
    result = async_run(user_has_email())
```

What is the proper way to test `test_user_has_email`?